# How to trigger methods on created() instead of v-on:click for tags with conditions?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With the code bellow I'm displaying an element's info on click.

Right now when I click an element on the page it gets all the details about this object using this method:

```html
<div @click="getFolderDetails(props.item)>
  ...
</div>
```

The question is, how do I get that data (run the method) not on `@click` but when the element is loaded (on `created()`)?

---

#### Method:

```
getFolderDetails (value) {
  this.objectTypeClicked = 'folder'        
  this.folderDetails = [
    {title: "name", value: value.name}, 
    {title: "type", value: "folder"}, 
    {title: "created", value: this.$options.filters.prettyDateTime(value.stat.birthtime)},
    {title: "modified", value: this.$options.filters.prettyDateTime(value.stat.mtime)},
    {title: "path", value: value.path}
  ]
}
```

Then it displays it within other elements on the page:

```html
<!-- display folder image if clicked has property value "folder" -->
<div v-if="objectTypeClicked == 'folder'">
  <img src="/static/folder.png" alt="">
</div>

...

<!-- display specified properties of the clicked object -->
<div v-if="objectTypeClicked == 'folder'">
  <div v-for="n in folderDetails" :key="n.id">
    <h2 v-if="n.title == 'name'">{{n.value}}</h2>
    <h3 v-if="n.value == 'folder'">folder</h3>
  </div>
</div>

...

<!-- display only some of the values of the clicked object (cut off the first 2) -->
<div v-if="objectTypeClicked == 'folder'">
  <div v-for="(i, index) in folderDetails" :key="index.id">
    <h3 v-if="index > 1">
      {{i.title}} - {{i.value}}
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Computed (takes data from store):

```
folderDetails: {
  get () {
    return this.$store.state.Info.folderDetails
  },
  set (value) {
    this.$store.commit('loadFolderDetails', value)
  }     
},
objectTypeClicked: {
  get () {
    return this.$store.state.Info.objectTypeClicked
  },
  set (value) {
    this.$store.commit('getObjectTypeClicked', value)
  }     
}
```

I know the code is far from optimal, but I'm still learning Vue.

Comment: @acdcjunior do you mean this `getFolderDetails(props.item)` ? This div is inside of an iterator component, so `props.item` is an object containing all the properties about the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a computed for this. Use the method to change the folder you want to display, let's say `currentFolder` and assign a default on mount, like `folderDetails[0]`, directly in the computed if `this.currentFolder` is null.

The computed would look like:

```
folderDetails() {
  let value = this.folderDetails[0];      
  if (this.currentFolder != null) {
    value = this.currentFolder;
  }

  return [
    {title: "name", value: value.name}, 
    {title: "type", value: "folder"}, 
    {title: "created", value: this.$options.filters.prettyDateTime(value.stat.birthtime)},
    {title: "modified", value: this.$options.filters.prettyDateTime(value.stat.mtime)},
    {title: "path", value: value.path}
  ]
}
```

and the method to set on click it would become

```
getFolderDetails (value) {
  this.objectTypeClicked = 'folder';
  this.currentFolder = value;
}
```

In general, I always prefer to set a default state of the loaded component so that everything "works" from start.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks for the answer, I"m gonna try that

Comment: @Un1 I added an example of how I would do it starting from your code ;)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the example, it's gonna save me at least an hour of struggling :)